# ASP page Form Action in Ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to call the `Form action` on `button` click to pass the data of page. For this, I defined the `OnClientClick` button method where I passed the `Ajax with Form action` . But this `Form action` always pass the data on second click, not on first click and also return the error from the ajax.
Is this the correct way to pass the data and call the form action with Ajax.
On Success of form action in Ajax,I want to redirect this page to some URL.

```
function redirect() {


    var pageUrl = '<%= ResolveUrl("ActionURL") %>';


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: pageUrl,
        data: $("#form").serialize(),


        success: function (data) {

            alert("pass");
//here rediect page to some url


        },
        error: function (data, success, error) {
            alert("Error1 : " + error);
        }
    });

    return false; } 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your ajax call inside `$(document).ready(function() {});`
Something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("selectorname").click(function() {
//Your function here for ajax call.
});
});
```